# Project not build in active configuration Visual Studio MacOS .net Core

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, xamarin, .net-core

I have created an Console Application(.Net Core) in Visual Studios MacOS Preview. In the project solution I don't see my program.cs also other things are not available it says *Project not built in active configuration*

[image]

whereas the project solution should look something like this

[image]

I have installed [.net core for macOS](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos). Also done with Homebrew configurations. I already had openssl & openssl@1.1 installed in osx so when I try to re-install openssl with homebrew it says

```
Warning: openssl is a keg-only and another version is linked to opt.
Use `brew install --force` if you want to install this version
```

On the other part to be sure that .net core works fine. I just compiled .net core C# application in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Have you updated to Preview 3? It is still a preview build, so bugs are expected.

Comment: @LexLi yes updated but this doesn't look bug to me. It's some configuration problem

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you do not have the [.NET Core SDK 1.0.0-rc4](https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/Sdk/rel-1.0.0/dotnet-dev-osx-x64.latest.pkg) installed.

Without the SDK installed Visual Studio for Mac Preview 3 will not find any SDK MSBuild files to import which results in no Debug/Release configurations being added to the project.

Visual Studio for Mac looks in the /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/ directory for the latest sdk. If there are no subdirectories in that directory then you do not have the SDK installed.

Also there are no files shown in the project which will also occur if there is no SDK found.

Currently Visual Studio for Mac does not have good error reporting about the missing SDK but this is planned for a future release.

Comment: The error is fixed but now I get this error `error MSB4057: The target "Build" does not exist in the project` googled for it but didn't fix any fixes for asp.net

Comment: Same issue as @AbhimanyuAryan here, after the preview 3 update error MSB4057: The target "Build" does not exist in the project

Comment: @Giuseppe - You need a recent version of Mono 4.8 for the build to work - https://dl.xamarin.com/MonoFrameworkMDK/Macx86/MonoFramework-MDK-4.8.0.459.macos10.xamarin.universal.pkg

Comment: @MattWard Why is Mono required for this to work - is it a dependency that VS has?

Comment: Yes it is a dependency. Currently the updater will not show it as a dependency for technical reasons. Visual Studio (Windows) depends on MSBuild 15 to compile .NET Core projects. Visual Studio for Mac also depends on MSBuild 15 and this is shipped with Mono 4.8. Earlier versions of Mono 4.8 were not including the latest bits to support compiling .NET Core projects.

Answer (score 11):

I got the same issue after VS update to build 1077. To resolve this issue you just need install [.NET Core SDK 1.0.0-rc4](https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/Sdk/rel-1.0.0/dotnet-dev-osx-x64.latest.pkg) and reinstall Mono 4.8, you can get it [here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=835346).

These information I got from changelog page  https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs-mac/preview/vs-mac-preview1/

I hope this will help.

Comment: Will that fix all fix the error MSB4057 BUILD does not exist in the project ?

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

For me on .netcore library project.

Remove project from solution (Right click on project > Delete > Remove)

And add it again. (Right click to solution > Add > Add Exist Project..)

Make sure SDK was already installed as Matt Ward mentioned.