# error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file

Tags: xamarin, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I have dotnet core version `1.0.0-rc4-004597` installed. Earlier it was working with [.NET Core 1.1](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos) & VS code. But at that time Visual Studio MacOS wasn't working. So [Matt suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41773344/project-not-build-in-active-configuration-visual-studio-macos-net-core) to install `1.0.0-rc4-004597` which fixed that issue with Visual Studio MacOS

but now there's this new issue with error MSB1003

```
~/Unity3D
⇨ cd GameReviewer
cd: no such file or directory: GameReviewer

~/Unity3D
⇨ mkdir GameReviewer

~/Unity3D
⇨ cd GameReviewer

~/Unity3D/GameReviewer
⇨ yo aspnet

     _-----_     ╭──────────────────────────╮
    |       |    │      Welcome to the      │
    |--(o)--|    │  marvellous ASP.NET Core │
   `---------´   │        generator!        │
    ( _´U`_ )    ╰──────────────────────────╯
    /___A___\   /
     |  ~  |
   __'.___.'__
 ´   `  |° ´ Y `

? What type of application do you want to create? Web Application Basic [without Membership and Authorization]
? Which UI framework would you like to use? Bootstrap (3.3.6)
? What's the name of your ASP.NET application? GameReviewer
   create GameReviewer/Dockerfile
   create GameReviewer/.bowerrc
   create GameReviewer/bundleconfig.json
   create GameReviewer/.gitignore
   create GameReviewer/bower.json
   create GameReviewer/appsettings.json
   create GameReviewer/project.json
   create GameReviewer/Program.cs
   create GameReviewer/Properties/launchSettings.json
   create GameReviewer/README.md
   create GameReviewer/Startup.cs
   create GameReviewer/web.config
   create GameReviewer/Controllers/HomeController.cs
   create GameReviewer/Views/_ViewImports.cshtml
   create GameReviewer/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml
   create GameReviewer/Views/Home/About.cshtml
   create GameReviewer/Views/Home/Contact.cshtml
   create GameReviewer/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
   create GameReviewer/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml
   create GameReviewer/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml
   create GameReviewer/wwwroot/css/site.css
   create GameReviewer/wwwroot/css/site.min.css
   create GameReviewer/wwwroot/favicon.ico
   create GameReviewer/wwwroot/images/banner1.svg
   create GameReviewer/wwwroot/images/banner2.svg
   create GameReviewer/wwwroot/images/banner3.svg
   create GameReviewer/wwwroot/images/banner4.svg
   create GameReviewer/wwwroot/js/site.js
   create GameReviewer/wwwroot/js/site.min.js


I'm all done. Running bower install for you to install the required dependencies. If this fails, try running the command yourself.


bower cached        https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.3.6
bower validate      3.3.6 against https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.3.6
bower cached        https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation.git#1.15.0
bower validate      1.15.0 against https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation.git#1.15.0
bower cached        https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive.git#3.2.6
bower validate      3.2.6 against https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive.git#3.2.6
bower cached        https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#2.2.3
bower validate      2.2.3 against https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#2.2.3
bower install       jquery-validation-unobtrusive#3.2.6
bower install       jquery-validation#1.15.0
bower install       jquery#2.2.3
bower install       bootstrap#3.3.6

jquery-validation-unobtrusive#3.2.6 wwwroot/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive
├── jquery#2.2.3
└── jquery-validation#1.15.0

jquery-validation#1.15.0 wwwroot/lib/jquery-validation
└── jquery#2.2.3

jquery#2.2.3 wwwroot/lib/jquery

bootstrap#3.3.6 wwwroot/lib/bootstrap
└── jquery#2.2.3


Your project is now created, you can use the following commands to get going
    cd "GameReviewer"
    dotnet restore
    dotnet build (optional, build will also happen when it's run)
    dotnet run



~/Unity3D/GameReviewer
⇨ cd GameReviewer

~/Unity3D/GameReviewer/GameReviewer
⇨ dotnet restore
MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.
```

Answer (score 4):

So Peter Marcu proposed a solution [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/440#issuecomment-274285377) for this problem. Running `dotnet migrate`