# Visual Studio MacOS error MSB4057: The target "Build" does not exist in the project

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, asp.net-core, compiler-errors

I have created a simple C# .net core console application project in VS MacOS. But I get error MSB4057. There a similar question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035414/target-build-does-not-exist-in-the-project-for-visual-studio) but doesn't explain anything how to fix this kind of error.

The problem is same when I create asp.net core project.

```
Build FAILED.

/Users/abhimanyuaryan/Unity3D/LearnCSharp/LearnCSharp/LearnCSharp.csproj : error MSB4057: The target "Build" does not exist in the project.
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.02

---------------------- Done ----------------------

Build: 1 error, 0 warnings
```

Comment: Have you installed .NET Core SDK from http://dot.net?

Comment: @LexLi I have installed .net core as suggested by Matt here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41773344/project-not-build-in-active-configuration-visual-studio-macos-net-core

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is very important to upgrade Mono 4.8 to its latest build, (in my case)

http://www.mono-project.com

Then the bundled build environment can successfully compile the project.

It seems the built in updater does not upgrade Mono runtime as expected.

Updated: Now the installer should assist you install Mono 5.0 automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I found this same issue when I downloaded the Xamarin mobile-samples from GitHub. This occurred in some of the shared library projects. Inside the project file (.csproj), the Project tag will have a DefaultTargets attribute of Build.

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

At the bottom of iOS and Android project files, there will be Import tags which include the Build template instructions.

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.CSharp.targets" />
```

or

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" />
```

However, some common library projects are missing the appropriate C# build instructions. The missing tag is:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

To fix this:

1. Unload the project file and edit it, either in Visual Studio or with a Text Editor.
2. At the bottom of the file, just before the closing </Project> tag, add the missing Microsoft.CSharp.targets Import tag.
3. Save the file and reload the project in the solution.